# R Using gsub and looping over dataframe column names

Tags: r, loops, gsub

I'm trying to loop over certain columns of my dataframe, replacing anything with characters with a 1 (and ignoring blank rows).

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Participant = 1:3, A = c("a", "a", ""), B = c("", "b", "b"), C = c("c", "c", "c")), .Names = c("Participant", "Q1_1", "Q1_2", "Q1_3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

If my columns to loop over are:

```
columns <- c("Q1_1", "Q1_3")
```

why doesn't this work?

```
for (i in columns) {
  df$i <- gsub(".+", 1, df$i, perl=TRUE)
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "i", value = character(0)) :replacement has 0 rows, data has 3
```

Comment: To add onto Rich's comment, `df$i` is looking for the column name `i` (as in the character string "i") while `df[[i]]` evaluates `i` first

Comment: `df[,i]` would typically be used for matrices (with colnames) or data.frames